# Problem with bibtopic package and sectioned bibliographies

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lyx, subdividing

I'm using LyX 2.0.1.5 on Windows 7 (MiKTeX 2.9.4813).

Since my thesis covers a very specific topic (QM of Retinal's Photoisomerization) I have to divide my Bibliography in two sections:

1. Essential Bibliography
2. Further Reading

First I looked up the package [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), which I found very useful for this purpose, the only bad thing is that I have to use only LyX (I even searched  http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex but the procedure described is too tricky).

After consulting the "Additional LyX Features" I searched the package [`bibtopic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic) and, after following to the letter the description on paragraph 3.1.2, I get this unexpected looking division:

> ### Essential Bibliography
>
> `[1]` Document...
>
> `[2]` Document...
>
> ### Further Reading
>
> `[3]` Document...
>
> `[4]` Document...

The problem is that the citation numbering doesn't stop for each paragraph, even if two BibTeX Bibliographies have been generated; maybe it is determined by the absence of an appropriate Bibliography title: since [`bibtopic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bibtopic) removes it, I had to manually re-add that (as a `\chapter*` or `\section*`, for instance).

I know that [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) offers a better result, since the citation numbering is divided properly, but to use this feature I have to switch to TeXworks:

> ### Essential Bibliography
>
> `[1]` Document...
>
> `[2]` Document...
>
> ### Further Reading
>
> `[1]` Document...
>
> `[2]` Document...

So can I still use BibTeX (and the related extensions) and be able to generate the same result as `biblatex`?

P.S.: I apologize fot the possibly bad English and the request itself, because on other forums I've been told to switch directly to [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) and forget about LyX.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, please write to lyx-users@lists.lyx.org. There are a couple of knowledgeable `biblatex` LyX-users who hang out there.

Comment: @scottkosty thanks for the advice! Maybe I asked for a solution too specific for the topic `BibTeX` and related packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, with BibTeX and LyX it is possible to generate such bibliographies. It is just a setting of an option of the `bibtopic` package in an indirect way. Its document mentioned the following package option.

> `sectcntreset`
>   Reset the numerical label for the bibliography items for
>   each `btSect` environment to '1'. (The default is continuous
>   numbering.) **Note**: This makes only sense when having at most one
>   `\btPrintCited` command in all your `btSect` environments; otherwise,
>   the citation labels in the document won’t be unique any more! The bad
>   thing is that you will get **no warning** from LaTeX about
>   '`multiply-defined labels`' in this case – so please use this option
>   with care.

Add `sectcntreset` in the field "Custom" of "Document Settings > Document Class > Class options" as a workaround since LyX does not allow to set a package option of `bibtopic` directly. (If the field "Custom" is not empty then you need to append it with a comma: `,sectcntreset`.) Then `sectcntreset` is applied to *all* LaTeX packages and hopefully no other package conflicts with having this package option set.